# How to reference the current collection rendering variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following collection rendering code:

```
<%= render partial: 'product_models/attr_val',
           collection: attr_vals.sort_by {|attr_val| attr_val.name},
           as: :attr_val,
           locals: {input_type: "checkbox",
                   is_input_checked: checked_attr_vals_ids.include?(WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE.id),
                   is_input_disabled: true} %>
```

Is there any way I can reference the current object (`attr_val`) in the `locals`? If it is possible, what should I replace `WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE` with?

Comment: Why can't you pass `checked_attr_vals_ids: checked_attr_vals_ids` into the partial, then put the `.include?` inside there?

Comment: I want to avoid passing unnecessary data. This can be checked earlier.

Comment: What is `attr_val` and does it include data that let's you determine if input is checked?

Comment: This is just a sample code. The important piece of this thread is the question: can the current variable of the collection being rendered be referenced? If so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to me that the answer is: No, you cannot reference the current variable of the collection being rendered in the way that you have formulated the question. But, perhaps a wiser person than I will know how to do it.

Comment: Not the best option, but you could do a loop and call the partial individually.